# How to call a specific value within the functions.php file?

Tags: php, functions

*Hi all, I'm a newb here, but hoping someone might have the answer to my question.*

Within my functions.php file, I have this code:

```
//Contractor Page meta box details
$contractorpage_meta_box=array();
$contractorpage_meta_box[]=array(
    'id'=>'contractor-page-meta-box',
    'title'=>'Contractor Page Details',
    'page'=>'contractor-page',
    'context'=>'normal',
    'priority'=>'high',
    'fields'=>array(
            array(
                'id'=>"header_link_heading1",
                'label'=>"First Header Link Heading",
                'name'=>"header_link_heading1",
                'type'=>"text"
            ),
            array(
                'id'=>"header_link_text1",
                'label'=>"First Header Link Text",
                'name'=>"header_link_text1",
                'type'=>"text"
            ),
            array(
                'id'=>"header_link_url1",
                'label'=>"First Header Link Url",
                'name'=>"header_link_url1",
                'type'=>"text"
            ),
            array(
                'id'=>"header_link_heading2",
                'label'=>"Second Header Link Heading",
                'name'=>"header_link_heading2",
                'type'=>"text"
            ),
            array(
                'id'=>"header_link_text2",
                'label'=>"Second Header Link Text",
                'name'=>"header_link_text2",
                'type'=>"text"
            ),array(
                'id'=>"header_link_url2",
                'label'=>"Second Header Link Url",
                'name'=>"header_link_url2",
                'type'=>"text"
            ),array(
                'id'=>"page_heading",
                'label'=>"Page Heading",
                'name'=>"page_heading",
                'type'=>"text"
            ),array(
                'id'=>"page_sub_heading",
                'label'=>"Page Sub Heading",
                'name'=>"page_sub_heading",
                'type'=>"text"
            ),array(
                'id'=>"first_intro_text",
                'label'=>"First Intro Text",
                'name'=>"first_intro_text",
                'type'=>"text"
            ),array(
                'id'=>"second_intro_text",
                'label'=>"Second Intro Text",
                'name'=>"second_intro_text",
                'type'=>"text"
            ),array(
                'id'=>"video_link",
                'label'=>"Video link",
                'name'=>"video_link",
                'type'=>"text"
            ),array(
                'id'=>"main_content_heading",
                'label'=>"Main Content Heading",
                'name'=>"main_content_heading",
                'type'=>"text" 
            ),array(
                'id'=>"main_content_text",
                'label'=>"Main Content",
                'name'=>"main_content_text",
                'type'=>"wysiwyg"
            ),array(
                'id'=>"bottom_heading",
                'label'=>"Bottom Heading",
                'name'=>"bottom_heading",
                'type'=>"text"
            ),array(
                'id'=>"bottom_content",
                'label'=>"Bottom Content",
                'name'=>"bottom_content",
                'type'=>"text"
            ),array(
                'id'=>"bottom_link_text",
                'label'=>"Bottom Link Text",
                'name'=>"bottom_link_text",
                'type'=>"text"
            ),array(
                'id'=>"bottom_link_url",
                'label'=>"Bottom Link Url",
                'name'=>"bottom_link_url",
                'type'=>"text"
            ),array(
                'id'=>"right_first_line",
                'label'=>"First Line Right Column",
                'name'=>"right_first_line",
                'type'=>"text"
            ),array(
                'id'=>"right_last_line",
                'label'=>"Last Line Right Column",
                'name'=>"right_last_line",
                'type'=>"text"
            )
        )
);
```

I also have this code:

```
// Embed YouTube videos with "youtube" shortcode

function youtube($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "value" => '',
        "width" => '475',
        "height" => '350',
        "name"=> 'movie',
        "allowFullScreen" => 'true',
        "allowScriptAccess"=>'always',
    ), $atts));
    return '<object style="height: '.$height.'px; width: '.$width.'px"><param name="'.$name.'" value="'.$value.'"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="'.$allowFullScreen.'"></param><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="'.$allowScriptAccess.'"></param><embed src="'.$value.'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="'.$allowFullScreen.'" allowScriptAccess="'.$allowScriptAccess.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"></embed></object>';
}
add_shortcode("youtube", "youtube");
```

I'm trying to place the "video_link" from the first code into "value" from the second code (where it says "WHAT-TO-PUT-HERE".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: WordPress already does YouTube embedding, see: [http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function youtube($atts) {

    global $post;
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_link', true);

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(    //Make sure not to include the 'value' as part of this array. 
        "width" => '475',
        "height" => '350',
        "name"=> 'movie',
        "allowFullScreen" => 'true',
        "allowScriptAccess"=>'always',
    ), $atts));
    return '<object style="height: '.$height.'px; width: '.$width.'px"><param name="'.$name.'" value="'.$value.'"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="'.$allowFullScreen.'"></param><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="'.$allowScriptAccess.'"></param><embed src="'.$value.'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="'.$allowFullScreen.'" allowScriptAccess="'.$allowScriptAccess.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"></embed></object>';

}
```